# Vuetify calendar @click:more fire the @click:day

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuetify.js

I run into a issue for the v-calendar component, to stay simple, i have a `@click:date` and a `@click:day` event who do the same things (open a modal).

I see if the calendar have multiples event is not native supported and a button with more event is display ([see this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#props-event-more-text))

The get event we have to use is `@click:more`, the problem is when i click on the button more `@click:day` is fireup at the same time.

So, the solution is for me pretty simple, as a modifier stop `@click.stop:more` or `@click:date.more`, but i got the following error `$event.stopPropagation is not a function`.

Now, i'm not really sur what i need, i have the same issue for the click `@click:event` i fixed that by use the slot event and set a @click on the element.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by what i think a not good way.
But this works like expect and affect nothing, if we can't use a .stop event is maybe the good way.

Remove the `@click:day` on you'r v-calendar balise, add inside a template:

```
<template v-slot:day="day">
  <div class="tw-h-full" @click="openModalDay(day)" />
</template>
```

> *Tw-h-full is use to take the entire height of the day.
> Note the fact, no template is available for the more button.*

And add on the v-calendar the `@click:more`, all works fine and no trigger event at the same time.